# websocket chat rooms with node.js

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

have a module with "websocket.server":

```
const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
wsServer = module.exports =  {};

wsServer.init = (server) => {
    wsServer.ws = new WebSocketServer({server: server});

    wsServer.ws.on('connection', function msg_connection(ws) {
        ws.on('message', function msg_incoming(message) {

        });
    });
};
```

and "sender function" to all users that join my url like "site.com/chat/1":

```
//require websocket server
var messageSocket = require('../websocket/websocketServer');

messageSocket.ws.clients.forEach((client) => {
  client.send(JSON.stringify({
    type: 'text',
    message: messageText
  }));
});
```

it works fine, all users recieve their messages, but the problem that i have others links with other chats, like "site.com/chat/2" and "site.com/chat/3", how i can separate chats? mean make this chats as "rooms"

Comment: You will have to keep track (on the server) of which webSocket connections belong in which "chat room" and then when you want to send a message to a particular room, you iterate through only the sockets that are in that room and send just to them.  FYI, this functionality is built-in to socket.io (it has chat rooms built in) if you can use that on both client and server.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, i understand the logic but i can't undestand how to do it, can't use socket.io, need this functionality only via WS (

Comment: Are you just expecting us to write the code for you?  Or, where did you get stuck when you tried to write it yourself?